# Open Bluetooth Device Linkey File

Tags: bluetooth

I am looking for advice on how to locate and open a bluetooth mouse lynkey file on Ubuntu 17.10 so that I can copy the entries in my windows system. I have tried the following:

```
/var/lib/bluetooth/(myadapteraddress)/linkkeys  
/var/lib/bluetooth/<adapter address>/<remote device address>/info
edit /var/lib/bluetooth/[mac address of Bluetooth]/linkkeys
/var/lib/bluetooth/${DEVICE}/${ADDRESS}/info 
/var/lib/bluetooth/[mac address of Bluetooth]
/var/lib/bluetooth/AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA/BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB
```

I used `hcitool dev` to get the MAC address
so far nothing I've tried has worked and there seems to be confusion as to where bluetooth linkeys are actually stored in Ubuntu and from that premis how to open the location and view its contents.
I've used Ubuntu for over 8 years but this has stumped me.
Any advice or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution.

Open Nautilus via terminal with su for full root:

Using Nautilus navigate to bluetooth via file option using - var – lib - bluetooth

From Bluetooth open the 12 digit number (machine MAC address) opens up to device MAC address

Open device MAC

Opens to Info folder

Open Info – displays Linux LinkKey data - either save a copy or print screen / file or print a copy to use later in this process. It makes inputting the Linux LinkKey much easier.